# How to prove this determinant is $\pi$?

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, determinant, continued-fractions

> prove or disprove
>   $$\pi=\begin{vmatrix}
> 3&1&0&0&0&\cdots\\
> -1&6&1&0&0&\cdots\\
> 0&-1&\dfrac{6}{3^2}&1&0&\cdots\\
> 0&0&-1&\dfrac{3^2\cdot 6}{5^2}&1&\cdots\\
> 0&0&0&-1&\dfrac{5^2\cdot 6}{3^2\cdot 7^2}&\cdots\\
> 0&0&0&0&-1&\dfrac{3^2\cdot 7^2\cdot 6}{5^2\cdot 9^2}&\cdots\\
> 0&0&0&0&0&-1&\dfrac{5^2\cdot 9^2\cdot 6}{3^2\cdot 7^2\cdot 11^2}&\cdots\\
> \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\ddots\\
> \end{vmatrix}$$

I found maybe this is true.and is very interesting,(It seems Euler proved it?),because this  follows from the Euler result:

$$\pi=3+\dfrac{1^2}{6+\dfrac{3^2}{6+\dfrac{5^2}{6+\dfrac{7^2}{6+\cdots}}}}$$

and can we solve it? Thank you

Comment: What is the general expression for the $n$-th term on the diagonal?

Comment: @JimmyK4542,I have edit,wait it

Comment: According to Wikipedia's ["Tridiagonal Matrix" article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix#Determinant), the determinant here can be found via a recurrence relation $$f_{-1} = 0 \qquad f_{1} = 1 \qquad f_n = a_n f_{n-1} + f_{n-2}$$ where $a_n$ is the $n$th diagonal element (starting with $a_1$ in the upper-left). So, we don't really need to see the matrix form to study this problem.

Comment: But How find this $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_{n}$?

Comment: @chinamath: Well, finding the limit is the challenge. :)  I'm only observing that your determinant reduces to a simple recursion, so you don't really have to format the problem using a giant matrix. (Oh, and I typo'd. I should have $f_0 = 1$, not $f_1 = 1$.)

Comment: Looking at the continued fraction of $\pi$ should give you a clue where does the determinant come from! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#Continued_fractions

Answer (score 1):

A proof can be found on pages 11-13 of [An Elegant Continued Fraction for $\pi$](http://www.math.binghamton.edu/dikran/478/Ch7.pdf). Try deriving from the Leibnitz formula $1 - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} - ... = \frac{\pi}{4}$